# Including encrypted key in url

Tags: c#

I have an encrypted url that gets passed in as a query string such as

```
myurl.com/key/cYtLPBlnOUOi+8413hTQLz+GGeoiLeLhbPuNhK+saqhc/f/FgtKSbcInVB9IIoWER71L1Q6vrnLv8o3eKI843|M==
```

I am having issues, I believe due to the special characters such as the forward slash. How can I accept this url?

Comment: you need to encode the value before appending it to the URL

Comment: The encryption isn't the point, what you have is a piece of base64 data.

Comment: @HenkHolterman why isn't it a problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the Base64 came from. You just have to make it Url-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Web (Project > References > Add reference > System.Web)

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YOUR_STRING);
```